# Link mix "Unicode" and "MultiByte" libraries safety

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, character-encoding

It is safe (on runtime) to link mix "Unicode" and "MultiByte" libraries?

**e.g.**
(UniDll)     DLL that compiled with "Unicode".
(MBDll)      DLL that compiled with "MultiByte".
(UniStatic)  Static library that compiled with "Unicode".
(MBStatic)  Static library that compiled with "MultiByte".

(1) Link "UniDll" to "MBDll".
(2) Link "MBStatic" to "UniDll".
(3) Link "UniStatic" to "MBDll".

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario: check inside the static library with a proper IDE (Visual Studio, perhaps Eclipse..), and see how the names are structured (are they in seperate enums/classes/etc). You just want to avoid scope clash/symbol redefinition.